# Field value query with special character and unfiltered search returning unexpected results?

Tags: indexing, marklogic, marklogic-7

Field value query is giving unexpected results when any **special character(@,=,#,$,%,^,*)** is passed.

please find the 4 sample docs I have inserted in to ML.

```
<root>
    <journalTitle>Dinesh</journalTitle>
    <sourceType>JA</sourceType>
    <title>title1</title>
    <volume>volume0</volume>
</root>

<root>
    <journalTitle>Gayari</journalTitle>
    <sourceType>JA</sourceType>
    <title>title1</title>
    <volume>volume0</volume>
</root>

<root>
    <journalTitle>Dixit</journalTitle>
    <sourceType>JA</sourceType>
    <title>title1</title>
    <volume>volume0</volume>
</root>

<root>
    <journalTitle>Singla</journalTitle>
    <sourceType>JA</sourceType>
    <title>title1</title>
    <volume>volume0</volume>
</root>
```

**CTS Query :**

```
cts:search(
  fn:doc(),
  cts:field-value-query("Sample","#@#@#@*()", ("unwildcarded")),
  "unfiltered"
)
```

On running this query I am getting all the documents.

As per my understanding, it should return an **empty sequence**.

please find below the field I have created.

**Field (in XML format) :**

```
<field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database">
    <field-name>Sample</field-name>
    <field-path>
        <path>/root/journalTitle</path>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
    </field-path>
    <word-lexicons/>
    <included-elements/>
    <excluded-elements/>
    <tokenizer-overrides/>
</field>
```

**Index setting:**

[image: Index setting]

If I will add any alphabet(s) in the search string it will give me the correct results.

**Like:**

- @#$%F
- =====S
- df===$d

Please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try passing "exact" as an option to `cts:field-value-query`:

```
cts:search(
  fn:doc(),
  cts:field-value-query("Sample","#@#@#@*()", ("exact")),
  "unfiltered"
)
```

MarkLogic has an index for exact values to help in cases like this.  Note it's only on when you have both case sensitive and diacritic sensitive indexes enabled (which you do).  I know this works for `cts:element-value-query` so I expect it will for `cts:field-value-query` as well.

Comment: Yes, that will give me the correct results. I have tried this one. But I can not use this one as I am passing `case-insensitive` in the options as I need `case-insensitive` search. If we pass both `case-insensitive` & `exact`, an exception will be thrown - `Invalid option`

Comment: On setting the stemmed search to `advanced` the problem is resolved.
But I am having the same problem with `cts:element-word-query`.
Any solution?

Comment: Clearly your actual needs are beyond those asked in the question, since you're talking about needing case insensitivity and stemming. So I'm not sure what exactly you need. You may benefit from having your field define those punctuation characters as "symbols" which allows them to be indexed and considered reliably in unfiltered searches, where punctuation is usually ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Use instead the 'exact' option in the field-value-query.

This requires the fast diacritic- and case-sensitive options, but you already have those enabled.

You can also try xdmp:plan before and after using 'exact' to see the effect on the query plan.

Comment: On setting the stemmed search to `advanced` the problem is resolved. But I am having the same problem with `cts:element-word-query`. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the 'tokenizer overrides' option for your field, add these special character(@,=,#,$,%,^,*) as words (select 'word').

These special characters are not considered for matching by default. You need to override the default tokenizer to include them as words.

Answer (score 0):

May I know what output are you expecting on passing this cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("journalTitle"),"=====S") for the above given for xmls.

Comment: "=====S" will give me the correct results which is empty sequence because as I mentioned if we include any alphabet in the search string it's working as expected..... On passing only special characters("===", "&@&@") I am getting some results, in above case getting all the documents.... But I am expecting empty sequence...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the one character searches to true in database config, resolves the issue in element-word-query.

Comment: One character search indexes will take lot of space!! Can't afford it.